# How to select specific entities from a view made as an REST export

Tags: views, entities

I have made a REST export from a view, which is fine when I set it up to SHOW "FIELDS", which I select and define myself.

My issue is if I set it up to show: "ENTITY", then I get a HUGE result set which loads very slow.

Is there a way where it is possible to also select/define the specific entities you are interested to use in the result set, instead of everything? Pretty much just like when the SHOW option is set to FIELDS?

Comment: May be I'm missing something here? what's the issue using 'Fields' here? select fields as necessary, if the fields are in other entity (say content type) use relationship to get them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply laymannx, I am new to Drupal so it might be me that is missing something :-) Thing is that when SHOW was set to FIELDS, then I got output wrapped in HTML for some fields. Which I don't want - I just saw that it is possible to select "RAW" for the field settings, which looks like doing what I was actually after in the first place :-)